# Special Price From Date and Special Price To Date not visible in backend M2

Tags: magento2, price, backend, date, special-price

I am working on Magento Enterprise 2.2.5, I want to set a special price for some products but Special Price From Date and Special Price To Date are not visible. Can someone have an idea how we can add these to products?

According to Magento docs, we should have a date
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-price-special.html

https://gmkr.io/s/5bb47cb8f30a05168c6836cb/0

Comment: maybe this [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5984#issuecomment-360345397) will help you

Comment: But they have done modification in mailchimp/mc-magento2 module. I am not sure how this module is related to backend part

Comment: follow this [link](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/catalog/product-price-special.html) to add To date and From date in Enterprise Edition

Comment: I followed the link add schedule update for product but it still doesn't seem to work on frontend. Still have regular price

Comment: you can add special price and from 2 to date  in products via csv.
adding these columns in your csv :
special_price 
special_price_from_date
special_price_to_date
Date format is like : 3/21/19

Comment: @Daniel_12 are you able to solve this ?i am also not able to see this on my admin

Answer (score 1):

For enterprise Magento 2 versions, we need to schedule an update as mentioned here - https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/catalog/product-price-special.html

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the special price dates in admin by overriding the `attributesToEliminate` param in `Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav`, via your custom module's di.xml:

```
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="attributesToEliminate" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="news_from_date" xsi:type="string">news_from_date</item>
                <item name="news_to_date" xsi:type="string">news_to_date</item>
                <item name="custom_design_from" xsi:type="string">custom_design_from</item>
                <item name="custom_design_to" xsi:type="string">custom_design_to</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
```

This excludes the `special_from_date` and `special_to_date` items that are normally included via `vendor/magento/module-catalog-staging/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`